# can not decompress lz4 bytes in python

Tags: python, redis, lz4

```
import redis                                        
import lz4framed                                    
class TestWXRedis(unittest.TestCase):               
    def test_t(self):      
        r=redis.StrictRedis(host=xxx, port=xxxx)                
        result = r.hget("xxxxx","xxxx")                   
        print(result)                               
        print(lz4framed.decompress(result))
```

the output of result:

```
b'\xba\x00\x00\x00\xf0\xab\x8c\xa4date\xa6180320\xa6status\xc2\xa3aid\xa71204424\xa3cid\xaczg3Kx7pvYRGT\xa3pid\x03\xa2ad\xa528976\xa2ip\xaf183.193.180.218\xa4user\xa881564934\xa4opid\xbcoeEcCxC5_ayjWs_Cez8E5vdph_xY\xa2ei\xaf865454023352746\xa2ts\x00\xa3tid\xbb003f8uj1cnae0buvrfnnsq3lh6v'
```

and the error is:

```
ERROR: test_t (WXUserCollector.redi.wxredis_test.TestWXRedis)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ymserver/tmp/zengjiwen/wx_public_account/WXUserCollector/redi/wxredis_test.py", line 14, in test_getYmUserInfoByAppidOpenid
    print(lz4framed.decompress(result))
_lz4framed.Lz4FramedError: ('ERROR_frameType_unknown', 13)
```

Comment: I used php to compress an array with lz4, then stored the compressed result by Redis. Now, i want to get the compressed data from Redis by python, but i got an error aboved while decomporessed the result. The compressed date could be decompressed correctly by other program language except python. I just want to know why error occured  when decompressed in python   Thank you :)

Comment: You could try these [python LZ4 bindings](https://pypi.org/project/lz4/) rather than the framed bindings.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue from [faust](https://faust.readthedocs.io/) -> [aiokafka](https://github.com/robinhood/aiokafka)
`lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiokafka/record/default_records.py", line 186, in _maybe_uncompress
    uncompressed = lz4_decode(data.tobytes())
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
`

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue. Turned out block compression was done, so block decompression is required.

```
import lz4.block
uncompressed_size = 8192
decompressed_data = lz4.block.decompress(compressed_data_base64, uncompressed_size=uncompressed_size)
```